# search mysql table after specific id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, logic

I am working with a TABLE, need logical help.

Check the below URL for the table structure and sample data.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6da1ce/2

I am trying to fetch records after a specific value.

Check the following:

My db has the following datas.

```
Id ---- Value
1       3
2       6
3       7
4       8
5       9
6       2
7       3
```

I am searching for the value 7, after the appearance of  7 in Id 3, I want to search for the next ID's after that such as 8,9,2,3.

I am trying to write a query to get the records after the first appearance of 7.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE value = 7
            limit 1)
```

in my case:

```
SELECT * from journal 
WHERE journal_id > (SELECT journal_id from journal WHERE id = 7
                    limit 1)
```

How can I write this in single Query:

I know only the value from where the search should begun.

Can I search using limit instead of mentioning Unique ID? Also can I get the remaining search in DESC order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am searching for the value 7, after the appearance of 7 in Id 3, I want to search for the next ID's after that such as 8,9,2,3.*

```
SELECT * FROM journal
WHERE journal_id > (
                    SELECT MIN(journal_id)
                    FROM journal
                    where id=7
                    )
AND id=7
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ceb83/5)

Comment: The `and id=7` is not correct, but I upvoted anyway.